# I was created Spa module DotNetNuke using Visual Studio 2015. When i build the project i'm facing this error

Tags: projects-and-solutions

Assembly 'DotNetNuke.Web' with identity 'DotNetNuke.Web, Version=9.1.1.129, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http' with identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: where is the code that produces this error? how should anyone help you without that?

Comment: I've got a similar issue when trying to install Peter Donker's React Demo Module:
https://github.com/DNN-Connect/DNNConnect-2016-Demo-ReactJs